# counting number of three digit numbers in a text file

Tags: files, batch

I have a text file with hundreds of three digit numbers.
For example:

```
 0  2  3
 0  2  3
 0  2  9
 0  3  9
 0  9  2
 0  9  2
 0  9  9
 1  2  2
 1  2  2
 1  2  2
 1  2  9
 1  2  9
 1  3  3
 1  9  2
 1  9  2
 1  9  2
 1  9  3
 1  9  9
 1  9  9
 1  9  9
 1  9  9
 2  0  2
 2  0  3
 2  0  9
 2  1  2
 2  1  2
 2  1  3
 2  1  9
 2  1  9
 2  2  4
 2  2  5
 2  2  5
 2  2  5
 2  2  6
 2  2  6
 2  2  8
```

I want to convert this to show how many of each number is in the file to look something like this:

```
 0  2  3     2
 0  9  2     2
 1  2  2     3
 etc
```

Comment: the number do not display the right way after I posted the question.  Sorry

Comment: Are those numbers all composed of single digits? If so, you can create a linear array of 1000 and use the numbers as indices to count their occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

`sort -n numbers.txt | uniq -c | sed -E 's/^( *[0-9]+) (.*)$/\2 \1/'` would be the simplest way to achieve your goal. It:

- `sort`s your **n**umbers first, just in case
- **c**ounts the length of each `uniq`ue set
- `sed`s the result to move the count to the rear of each string

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the lines consist of sequences of digits is largely irrelevant - unless you want to do arithmetic on the numbers themselves you can count / uniquify them just like any other strings e.g. using an associative array or hash:

```
awk '{c[$0]++} END {for (i in c) printf "%s\t%d\n", i, c[i]}' numbers.txt
```

or

```
perl -lnE '$c{$_}++ }{ for $k (keys %c) { say "$k\t$c{$k}" }' numbers.txt
```